# How to convert a CSV file to CSV UTF-8 (Comma Delimited) using a command in linux terminal?

Tags: linux, shell, unix, terminal

I already have the spreadsheet saved inside the directory with the name 'status.csv' how can I see what type of csv and change it to CSV UTF-8 (Comma Delimited) using just the terminal?

Comment: There aren't many details in this question. What application did you use to create this spreadsheet? What does `file status.csv` output? What makes you think the file is not already in CSV format?

Comment: If you want to convert from one character encoding to another, use `iconv`.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to convert the `;` separators into commas, you can use `sed` (assuming the data does not contain any `|` symbol):

```
sed -i "s|;|,|g" status.csv
```

The flag `-i` means in place editing. You can remove it when testing.

If the data contains one or more pipe characters, you can use another separator for `sed`, as in the following command:

```
sed -i "s@;@,@g" status.csv
```

The command that is used most for checking a file type is `file`, but it just displays `ASCII text` for a `.csv` file AFAICS. I don't know any others.